# ArrayList and non-specificity when retrieving objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Firstly apologies for the question - I am new to Java and just could not think of a good way to phrase it.

I have an abstract class called "Animal" and some specific classes called "Pig", "Horse" etc that inherit from "Animal".

I am using an ArrayList to create a list of animals, which are instantiated Pigs, Horses etc. I then want to pull Animals off the list and work with them, but Java will then only allow me to interact with them if they are the base class, Animal.

Here is a quick listing of my Main code that should make this clearer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Pig("Porkey", "pink"));
        Animal animal = animals.get(0);
        animal.introAnimal(animal);
        animal.oink(); // Won't compile.Specific Pig class method   
    }
}
```

Now I know I can cast with "`Pig animal = (Pig) animals.get(0)`" but my point is that I want to be able to work with these animals regardless of what they are and use getObjectType or some such later on if I need to know.

It seems almost as if this a roadblock for polymorphism :) I am not too worried about this specific bit of code (I am just practicing) but more in the general solution to this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: This isn't a "roadblock for polymorphism", this is the entire purpose of polymorphism.  Specifically, interacting with multiple types *as if* they were the base type.  If you're in a situation where you need to know the specific types, then arguably polymorphism (i.e. using references to the base type) was the wrong approach.

Comment: Aye, but it won't let me treat the object as a Pig even though I know it is a pig - it refuses to compile. I would understand if it threw an exception at run time.

Comment: Of course it won't compile, Animal has no method `Oink`. You can either implement it as an abstract method in `Animal` (not advised, lacks style), cast the Object (see below) or encapsulate it in a general method so other animals can also perform similar tasks (also see below).

Comment: It was the casting that I was unsure how to do. I obviously would not want to do the above unless I was sure is was a pig. I get it now about checking and then casting ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use terms which are generic to Animals.  Instead of instructing the Animal to `oink` which doesn't apply to all animals, you could instruct it to `speak` which could be a generic term.

Java is a static typing language so the compiler will complain if you try to use methods which might not work at runtime.  It is not a dynamic language which allows you to call any method in the hope that it might work at runtime.  While this is more flexible, it is harder to reliably construct large programs. e.g. say I rename a method, how do I know who is calling that method to also rename it.

```
abstract class Animal {
    void speak();
}

class Pig extends Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Oink");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}

class Duck extends Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Qwack");
    }
}

List<Animal> animals = Arrays.<Animal>asList(new Dog(), new Pig(), new Duck);
for (Animal animal : animals)
    animal.speak();
```

prints

```
Woof
Oink
Qwack
```

> Thanks for your answer. The thing I was trying to get at is that I want to be able to create a list and then remove stuff from the list and be able to deal with the subclass depending on which subclass it is at run-time. I just didn't realise you could cast later on to get subclass methods.

There is two ways of doing this.

```
List<Animal> animals = ...
for (Animal animal: animals)
    if (animal instanceof Pig) {
        ((Pig) animal).oink();
    }
```

This still requires you to know you want a Pig.  Say you have another class `Boar` and it has an `oink` method as well, and you don't care that Pig and Boar haven't got a parent class (though you could)

```
List<Animal> animals = ...
for (Animal animal: animals) {
    Method method = animal.getClass().getMethod("oink");
    if (method != null)
        method.invoke(animal);
}
```

Now let say the method is not only not in `Animal` but it is `private` to Pig making it harder to call.

```
List<Animal> animals = ...
for (Animal animal: animals) {
    Method method = animal.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("oink");
    if (method != null) {
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(animal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing I was trying to get at is that I want to be able to create a list and then remove stuff from the list and be able to deal with the subclass depending on which subclass it is at run-time. I just didn't realise you could cast later on to get subclass methods.

Comment: @tentimes There is always more options.  I have listed three, others become increasingly more complicated.

Comment: Peter is there a reason why I would prefer your last paragraph of code over the "instaceof" in the sol4me answer above? You are both doing essentially the same thing but I am not sure which is better.

Comment: @tentimes you can use reflection if you want to call `oink` but you don't know or limit yourself to `Pig`s.

Comment: @tentimes if you can't decide who to upvote, give it to the one with less rep ;)

Comment: Nice, very informative, well formulated and conclusive!

Comment: Can I just check is the line "List<Animal> animals = ..." a shorthand or does the ... mean something else?

Comment: @tentimes it means you need to set it to something.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `instanceof` operator(The instanceof keyword can be used to test if an object is of a specified type.) to check if `animal` refers to `Pig` and if it does, then perform the cast and invoke specific method of Pig. E.g.

```
 ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Pig("Porkey", "pink"));
        Animal animal = animals.get(0);
        animal.introAnimal(animal);
  if (animal instanceof Pig)            
      ((Pig)animal).oink(); // This will compile and work
```

Comment: Ah, so you cast it when you use it by placing it within brackets and a Pig cast outside?

Comment: Yes but before casting I am making sure that `animal` can be casted to Pig(using `instanceof`). If you avoid this check, and directly cast the object , then you could end up with ClassCastException

Comment: Oh yes, I understand I need to be careful that it is actually a pig. I just didn't know you could cast like that. Good job :)

Comment: While this is a correct answer it's important to note that `instanceof` should be  measure of last resort. If the problem can be solved using inheritance, it would be a superior answer.

Comment: @ShellFish You are right, but I Guess OP (because OP already had created a method `introAnimal`, so OP seems to be aware of inheritance concept) was looking for a way how to cast an object to a specific type, that's why I haven't mentioned adding abstract method in `Animal` class.

Comment: @sol4me Yes I agree, I was just pointing out the controversy of using instanceof :)

Answer (score 1):

If you super class contains a method `execute()` for example and you implement this function in each of it's subtypes, the correct method will be executed.

Example:

```
class pig extends Animal {
    ...
    public void execute () {
        System.out.println("Oink");
    }
    public void specificPigAction {
        ... 
   }
}

class cat extends Animal {
    ...
    public void execute () {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
Animal pig = animals.get();
pig.execute(); // output = oink
Animal cat = animals.get();
cat.execute(); // output = meow
```

If you wish to perform very specific tasks that perhaps only a cat has you have to cast the Object to the correct type:

```
Pig pig = (Pig) animals.get();
pig.specificPigAction();
```

In the latter case it's important to cast only if you know the type is correct or surround it in a throw catch clause.

Note that this code might not be conform to style rules or even Java syntax, but the idea is clear I believe.

Comment: How can I test what type it is without using instanceof? My situation is that I want to retrieve these animals and then deal with them according to which type they are. If I understand correctly you think that instanceof is the wrong way to go for that? Thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: There are several options but instanceof is pretty much the best to typecheck (you could optionally implement your own comparison method by assigning an Enum value to each class and type check using ´equals´ or something but I don't think that's advised either). The most stylish way to do it is to implement the `execute()` method for each type and then handle the action there. This of course depends on the context etc. If there is a piece of code that is the same for multiple types you can call `super.execute()` and implement the 'intersecting', if you will, code there.